# Column Headers Dissapear when Creating Table

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have the following script that takes an xls file and creates an xlsx with a table (formatted as an actual table). The column headers appear as Column1 Column2 etc within the final table, rather than the actual headers found within the dataframe.

Is there a way to fix this? I also found myself creating a temporary xlsx file, copying it to include the table, and removing the temporary version. Is it possible to streamline this more?

Code:

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime 

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

demand = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\source.xls"
dfd = pd.read_excel(demand, sheet_name = 'sheet').fillna(0)
dfd = dfd.iloc[6:]
dfd.columns = dfd.iloc[0] #replace headers
dfd = dfd[1:] #remove headers from first row

destd = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\temporary.xlsx"
destd2 = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\File (" + str(date) + ").xlsx"
dfd.to_excel(destd)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(destd)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Demand")
worksheet.add_table('A1:DL10000', {'data': dfd.values.tolist()})
workbook.close()
destination = shutil.copy2(destd, destd2)

os.remove(destd)
```

Import Column Headers:

```
dictonary = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Dictionary - Column Headers.xlsx"

dfd = pd.read_excel(dictonary, sheet_name = 'Demand')
dict1 = dfd.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

From xlsxwriter's documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html):

```
The columns parameter can be used to set properties for columns within the table.
The sub-properties that can be set are header, header_format etc.
The column data must be specified as a list of dicts.
```

That means that you can add another key 'columnms' in the dictionary of the add_table method to rename the headers.

Here is an example of a table with the headers renamed:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John','George','Paul'],
                    'Age': [23,34,42]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# This will create a basic table with the headers named as 'Column 1' etc
#worksheet.add_table('A1:B4', {'data': df.values.tolist()})

# Add the 'columns' argument to name the headers
worksheet.add_table('A1:B4', {'data': df.values.tolist(),
                    'columns': [{'header': 'Name'},
                                {'header': 'Age'}]})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

***EDIT***

If your dataframe is imported from a file and you do not want to manually type all the header names you could do `'columns': [{'header': df.columns[0]}, {'header': df.columns[1]}]` etc or even better declare a variable and assign it a list comprehension:

```
header_names = [{'header': df.columns[x]} for x in range(df.shape[1])]
```

Then you just need to do:

```
worksheet.add_table('A1:B4', {'data': df.values.tolist(),
                    'columns': header_names})
```

Comment: I've tried loading in my column headers as a dictionary, but am having issues with making everything equate to 'header':_____. Whenever I load the data (70 column headers), it loads as 'header':___, 'header.1':___, 'header.2':___, etc. How would I avoid this?

Comment: Sorry but i can not understand exactly what the problem is, are your headers appearing as underscore symbols '_____'? You should create a minimal example and share it, your code includes files which we do not have access to.

Comment: Everything makes sense to me except the last part..  Instead of manually entering in each column header into the script like above ('columns': [{'header': 'Name'},            {'header': 'Age'}]}), I'd like to import the names from an Excel file. Is that possible?

Comment: Check my answer, i edited it to answer your question